# RCSB API: limited returned result

Tags: assembly, api

Is there a limit of query results on RCSB API?

Interestingly, no matter how to adjust my query criteria, only 10 assemblies are returned. Here is an example query json: (truncated from a longer query file)

```
{
  "query": {
    "type": "group",
    "logical_operator": "and",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "type": "terminal",
        "service": "text",
        "parameters": {
          "operator": "greater",
          "value": 1,
          "attribute": "rcsb_assembly_info.polymer_entity_instance_count"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "return_type": "assembly"
}
```

Example python code requesting query:

```
url_query = 'https://search.rcsb.org/rcsbsearch/v1/query?json='
query_str = open(query_json, 'r').read()
query_str = query_str.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')
url = url_query + query_str

r = requests.get(url)
content = r.content.decode('utf-8')
result = json.loads(content)
print(len(result['result_set']) # always equal to 10
```

Comment: Maybe ask RCSB at https://www.rcsb.org/pages/contactus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staff from rcsb kindly reminds me the [solution](https://search.rcsb.org/index.html#pagination) - add the following lines in the json query.

```
"request_options": {
"return_all_hits": true
}
```